# AS3 Can't access child of multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, multidimensional-array

Below is code sample of creating multidimensional  tableCardsOfPlayers array with keys of seat names like ("firstSeat", "secondSeat", etc.). And those keys should hold an array of "card1" => Card() references:

```
var players:Array = lastJoinedRoom.userList;
var cardsArray:Array = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5"];
tableCardsOfPlayers = new Array();
for each(var userTemp:User in players)
{
    var userVars:Array = userTemp.getVariables();
    var userVarDic:Array = new Array();
    var seat:String = userTemp.getVariable("seat").getStringValue();
    if(tableCardsOfPlayers[seat] == undefined) tableCardsOfPlayers[seat] = [];

    for each(var userVar:UserVariable in userVars)
    {
        if (cardsArray.indexOf(userVar.name) != -1)
        {
            tableCardsOfPlayers[seat][userVar.name] = new Card();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I access

```
 trace(tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]["card1"]);
```

AS3 debugger throws an exception

```
"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.";
```

What am I doing wrong? I've searched for similar questions here, checked every line, everything seems fine.

**Result of Recursive trace of tableCardsOfPlayers**

```
--- secondSeat :    
------ card2 : [object Card]   
------ card4 : [object Card]   
------ card3 : [object Card]   
------ card5 : [object Card]   
------ card1 : [object Card]   
--- firstSeat :    
------ card2 : [object Card]   
------ card4 : [object Card]   
------ card3 : [object Card]   
------ card5 : [object Card]   
------ card1 : [object Card]
```

[Debug picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtG97.jpg)

Recursive trace function:

```
public static function recursiveTrace (oObj:Object, sPrefix:String = ""):void  
    {  

        sPrefix == "" ? sPrefix = "---" : sPrefix += "---";  

        for (var i:* in oObj)  
        {  

            trace (sPrefix , i + " : " + oObj[i], "  ");  

            if (typeof( oObj[i] ) == "object") recursiveTrace ( oObj[i], sPrefix); // around we go again          
        }  

    }
```

Comment: What does userTemp.getVariable("seat").getStringValue() return?

Comment: It returns seat name, like "firstSeat"

Comment: Have you tried that with a debugger?

Comment: Yes, and debugger shows those keys. But when I trace the whole tableCardsOfPlayers array, values of those keys are somehow empty.. In recursive trace needed array values represented as above. I edited my question

Comment: Is this the line where the code crashes: tableCardsOfPlayers[seat][userVar.name] = "test"; ?

Comment: Sorry, the line is wrong, edited it. It goes like this: tableCardsOfPlayers[seat][userVar.name] = new Card(); And it doesn't crash here, it crashes when I try to access tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]["card1"]. Take a look at debugger trace above.

Comment: @kido25 According to your debug, that should work. Could you show how did you tried to access `tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]["card1"]` ?

Comment: @akmozo Like this: `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]["card1"]);`

Comment: @kido25 And what about the recursive trace of `tableCardsOfPlayers` ?

Comment: @akmozo Recursive trace is at the end of the question. Unless you're asking of something else.

Comment: @kido25 I mean, could you show the code for that ? and the result of : `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]);` ?

Comment: @akmozo Updated my question with sample of recursiveTrace(). The result of the `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers["firstSeat"]);` is `"TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."; `

Comment: @akmozo Please see Debug picture above

Comment: @kido25 I tested your code and it's working fine for me ...

Comment: @kido25 Could you try : `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers.firstSeat.card1);` ?

Comment: @akmozo I've traced array itself `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers);` And it showed nothing in the log, although it's not empty according to debug picture.

Comment: @kido25 Yes, I know, and I think that `trace(tableCardsOfPlayers.firstSeat.card1);` should work, try it ...

Comment: @akmozo Seems to be working) I've found my problem. Function, responsible for setting up `tableCardsOfPlayers` array had been calling only at 1 client at a time. Second client's `tableCardsOfPlayers` wasn't filled with anything and thus TypeError #1009. Thanks for your time, finally solved this.